# Set of numbers as a summation of two subsets

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, real-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Denote by $\mathbb{F}$ one of the set of (all) integer, rational, real or complex numbers.

We are looking for necessary and/or sufficient conditions for $\emptyset\neq C\subseteq \mathbb{F}$ such that
$C=A+B$ for some **non-singleton** subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{F}$.

Some obtained results:

**(1)** Every co-set of a non-trivial additive subgroup of $\mathbb{F}$ enjoys the property.

**(2)** If $1+C\subseteq C$ (e.g., all additive sub-semigroups containing 1), then $C=\{0,1\}+C$ and so the propety holds.

**(3)** All intervals of real numbers ($\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$) of the form $C=(0,c)$ satisfy the condition.

Any other idea (especially for finite sets)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi M.H.Hooshmand. are you interested in the case when $A$ and $B$ are finite of comparable size? because quite a bit can be said there. for example, if you have subsets $A,B$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of "positive density" (say $|A|=\alpha n$ and $|B|=\beta n$, where $n$ is sufficiently large in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$) then $A+B$ has to contain a long arithmetic progression. in general sumsets of this kind have much more structure than arbitrary subsets

Comment: (I'm not sure, but I suspect it may hard to say too much about the structural properties of such sets if you don't request that $A$ and $B$ have comparable size)

Comment: Hi Atticus Stonestrom. Thanks for your comment. For our study, only existence or absence of such subsets $A$ and $B$ is enough.